# regarding passing data to an array and error checking to make sure input was put in

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am working on an IOS app and i have a table view controller and 2 other view controllers connected to this table view with segues. I have the update function working correctly and all of it can communicate with each other by adding the protocol delegate part, here is the function I have for update and add:

```
   func updateRowData(stringToUpdate: String) {

    arrayOfLanguages[rowSelected] = stringToUpdate;
    self.tableView.reloadData();
    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true);

}


func addRowData(stringToAdd: String) {
    print("add function called")
    arrayOfLanguages.append(stringToAdd);
    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true);

}
```

The add part doesn't work at all except for the print part, so i know it is communicating to the view controller but I'm unsure how to fix it and I'm not sure how to error check either of those as well. If someone can help that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean?  If you step through it in the debugger, does it append new information to your array?  (...or if you print the array immediately before and after the append?)

Comment: show how you pass data between view controllers. I think this is your issue

Comment: ok when I debug it, it adds it to the array but doesn't display it in the table view controller

Comment: wait! I didn't do the reloaddata(), Ok that fixed it, how would I go about doing an error check to make sure something was inputted to the text field?